# Изменения размеров View

Tags: java, android

Я делаю приложение на Android, в котором пользователю нужно задать размеры битмапа, который мне нужно создать. Так как размеры могут быть больше размера экрана, то мой файл xml разметки имеет следующий вид:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_hor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        <com.painter.editor.PainterView
            android:id="@+id/painter_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Получается после начала работы програмы, я хочу изменить размер моего PaiterView.

```
package com.painter.editor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class PainterView extends View {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint paint;
    public boolean isDrawing;


    public PainterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        isDrawing = true;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для установки размера `Custom View` нужно переопределить метод `onMeasure` в котором вызвать метод `setMeasuredDimension`. Для запроса изменения размера нужно вызвать метод `requestLayout()`.

Тестовый пример.
Custom View:

```
public class ViewResizeable extends View{
    int bitmap_dx, bitmap_dy;

    public ViewResizeable( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ){
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    public void setSize( int dx, int dy ){
        bitmap_dx = dx;
        bitmap_dy = dy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ){
        super.onDraw( canvas );
        int text_size = 30;
        Paint paint = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
        paint.setTextSize( text_size );
        paint.setColor( 0xffffffff );
        canvas.drawColor( 0xff0080ff );
        canvas.drawText( "w/h: "+canvas.getWidth()+"/"+canvas.getHeight(), 0, text_size, paint );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ){
        super.onMeasure( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );
        setMeasuredDimension( bitmap_dx, bitmap_dy);
    }
}
```

Разметка активности:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mypack.ViewResizeable
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cutom_view"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dx"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="DX"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dy"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="DY"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="change size"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Активность:

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    ViewResizeable custom_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.test );
        custom_view = findViewById( R.id.cutom_view );
        custom_view.setSize( 512, 256 );
    }
    }

    public void onClick( View view ){
        int dx = Integer.parseInt( ((EditText)findViewById( R.id.dx )).getText().toString() );
        int dy = Integer.parseInt( ((EditText)findViewById( R.id.dy )).getText().toString() );
        custom_view.setSize( dx, dy );
        custom_view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```